# Arborvitae tree

Tags: trees, diagnosis

Our arborvitae was damaged by a lawn mower that hit the base of the tree.  About a 4th of the tree is now brown (likely dead).  If the dead section is removed, can the tree be resuscitated or alternatively are there nutrients that can be added to its base in order to rejuvenate the tree?
Thank you for any insight provided.

Pat

Comment: I have never seen an Arborvitae tree recover from being trimmed back to dead wood.  I have seen them fill in from other growth, but never from the branches that were damaged back to dead wood.  It is one of the major drawbacks.  If an owner doesn't keep up on annual trimming, it can get out of hand quickly.  In that case, the tree needs replaced.

Answer (score 0):

As EvilElf comments these plants do not recover like deciduous plants.  If they are ugly now it will be a long long time till new growth can hide the dead area.

Consider replacing it with a new one or have a lot of patience looking at the dead area until it grows over in a number of years